# Do the multiple postfix-expression(subscripting) evaluations result in UB

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   int  arr[7] = {0,1,2,3,4,3,2};
   arr[0]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr] = 5;  //#1
   for(auto i = 0;i<7;i++){
       std::cout<<i<<" : "<< arr[i]<<std::endl;
   }
}
```

Consider the above code, Is this evaluation at `#1` would result in UB? This is a example I have saw in [twitter](https://twitter.com/shafikyaghmour/status/1330695383073259523?s=20).

According to the evaluation sequence for postfix ++:
[expr.post.incr#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.post.incr#1)

> The value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced before the modification of the operand object.

That means, such a example would result in UB

```cpp
int arr[2] = {0};
(*(arr[0]++ + arr))++
```

Because, the side effect caused by expression `arr[0]++` and `(*(arr[0]++) + arr))++` are unsequenced and applied to the same memory location.

However, for the first example, It's difference. My argument is:
[expr.sub#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sub#1)

> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)),..., The **expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2**.

That means, every value computation and side effect associated with E1 are both sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with E2.

To simplify the expression at `#1`, according to the grammar of expression, such a expression should conform to:
[expr.ass](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.ass)

> logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause

And [expr.post#1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.post#1)

Where the `logical-or-expression` here is a postfix-expression.  That is,

```cpp
postfix-expression [ arr ] = 5;
```

Where the postfix-expression has the form `postfix-expression ++`, which in turn, the `postfix-expression` has the form `postfix-expression[arr]`. In simple, the left operand of assignment consists of two kinds of postfix-expressions, they alternate combination with each other.

> Postfix expressions group left-to-right

So, let the subscript operation has the form `E1[E2]` and the postfix++ expression has the form `PE++`, then for the first example, it will give a following decomposition like this:

```
E1': arr[0]++ 
E2': arr
E1'[E2']: arr[0]++[arr]
PE'++ : E1'[E2']++

E1'': PE'++
E2'': arr
E1''[E2'']: PE'++[arr]
PE''++: E1''[E2''] ++

and so on...
```

That means, in order to caculate `PE'++`, `E1'[E2']` should be calculated prior `PE'++`, which is identical to *((E1')+E2'), per the rule `E1'` is sequenced before `E2'`, hence the side effect caused by `E1'` is sequenced before value computation for `E2'`.
In other words, each side effect caused by postfix++ expression must be evaluated prior to that expression combined with the subsequent `[arr]`.

So, in this way, I think such a code at `#1` should have well-defined behavior rather than UB. Is there anything I misunderstand? Whether the code is UB or not? If it's not UB, what's the correct result the code will give?

Comment: Nice one. Took me a moment to process that expression.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Frankly, such a expression is so complex and hard to decompose them.

Comment: Nice question. But people should not write such code.

Comment: It's funny how you can build a train `0[arr][arr][arr][arr]`

Comment: @Bernd Agree. Just talk this example in sence.

Comment: @KamilCuk According to the grammar for postfix-expression, it indeed a well-formed expression.

Comment: @KamilCuk - A pirate train at at. Arr'!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe your understanding is fine and the code is fine in C++ from C++17.

> Is there anything I misunderstand?

No.

> Whether the code is UB or not?

No.

> If it's not UB, what's the result?

```
arr[0]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr] = 5;
Side effect: arr[0] := 0 + 1 = 1
       0[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr] = 5;
Side effect: arr[0] := 1 + 1 = 2
              1[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr] = 5;
Side effect: arr[1] := 1 + 1 = 2
                     1[arr]++[arr]++[arr]++[arr] = 5;
Side effect: arr[1] := 2 + 1 = 3
                            2[arr]++[arr]++[arr] = 5;
Side effect: arr[2] := 2 + 1 = 3
                                   2[arr]++[arr] = 5;
Side effect: arr[2] := 3 + 1 = 4
                                          3[arr] = 5;
Side effect: arr[3] := 5
```

I see the output would be:

```
0 : 2
1 : 3
2 : 4
3 : 5
4 : 4
5 : 3
6 : 2
```

---

Note that the part `The expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2` was added in C++17.

The code is undefined before C++17 and is undefined in C (the tweet was about C code), because in `arr[0]++[arr]++` both side effects on `arr[0]` from `++` are unsequenced to each other.

Comment: Agree with you, and the result in your answers is the same as I expect. In addition, if change the subscript operatation to unary* like *(E1+ E2), then that would cause UB, Right? As I have mentioned in question, `int arr[2] = {0};
(*(arr[0]++ + arr))++`

Comment: Totally, `(*(arr[0]++ + arr))++` is UB. The `The expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2` is crucial.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Nice one. and your caculation procedure is clear than that inhabited in my vscode :-)

Comment: In your second to last example, for `2[arr]++[arr] = 5;`, the side effect from `2[arr]++` is sequenced before the value computation of the second `arr`, which is sequenced before the assignment, so I don't see the UB there. Similarly for the last one. In other words, all side effects from the expressions on the left are sequenced before the value computation of the `arr` in the last `[arr]`, the last subscripting itself has no side effects, and its value computation is sequenced before the assignment, so it's that last `[arr]` that avoids UB from the final assignment in all cases.

Comment: `which is sequenced before the assignment` No, it isn't. The side effect of the _whole_ left expression are not sequenced with assignment. While the parts of computations are sequenced to each other in parts of the left expression of assignment in itself (ie. `2[arr]++` is computed before `[arr]`) the _whole_ left expression is unsequenced with assignment.

Comment: For your second to last example, I don't think that's UB. because `In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.` that means the value computation of expression `2[arr]++[arr] ` is sequence before assignment, and per `The expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2`, which in turn, is sequenced before assignment.

Comment: `the value computation` not, side effects. Yes, the _value computations_ of left expressions are computed before. The _side effects_ are not sequenced. So the _value_ is computed, but `arr[2] := ..` is not sequenced. That's the idea here.

Comment: [expr.ass]/1: *In all cases, the assignment is sequenced after the value computation of the right and left operands, and before the value computation of the assignment expression.* [expr.sub]/1: *The expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2* [intro.execution]/15: *An expression X is said to be sequenced before an expression Y if every value computation **and every side effect** associated with the expression X is sequenced before every **value computation** and every side effect associated with the expression Y*

Comment: Yes, in an expression of the form `e[f] = g`, `e` is sequenced before `f`, which means that the side effects of `e` are sequenced before the value computation of `f`, which is sequenced before the value computation of `e[f]`, which is sequenced before the side effect of `e[f] = g`.

Comment: Sequenced-before is a transitive relation [intro.execution]/8.

Comment: `in an expression of the form e[f] = g`: Yes, and the _value computation_ of `e[f]` is computed before assignment. The _side effects_ of `e[f]` are unsequenced to assignment.

Comment: @KamilCuk Consider  the expression `2[arr]++[arr]` as `E1[E2]`, which is the left operand of assignment, that means, the value computation of `E1[E2]` is sequenced before assignment, Right? In order to indentify E1[E2], the E1 and E2 should be evaluated, which per `The expression E1 is sequenced before the expression E2`, hence the side effect caused by `E1` is sequenced before value compuatation of `E1[E2]` which is sequenced before assignment.

Comment: @KamilCuk The side effects of `e[f]` (if any), yes, unsequenced with the assignment indeed, but the side effects of `e` are transitively sequenced before the assignment, because they are sequenced before the value computation of `f`.

Comment: By the way, the side effects of `f` are also unsequenced with the assignment, but, luckily, those `arr`s don't have side effects (which is inconsistent with general pirate knowledge - everybody knows *arr*s can have dire side effects - hat tip to [StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073276/do-the-multiple-postfix-expressionsubscripting-evaluations-result-in-ub#comment115043192_65073276)).

Comment: Och! I think I see that now, that makes sense. Thank you! You are right, I was wrong. For anyone reading the comments in the future, it refers to [the bottom of this edit of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65074770/2).

Comment: @bogdan  How could the `arrs` have side effects in a pirate train? Do you mean `arr[arr[0]++]`?

Comment: @jackX It's just a joke, nothing more, sorry for not marking it as such, I thought linking to the other comment would do it. I meant that when a pirate says *arr*, there can be serious... side effects :-) Getting back to C++, yes, you gave a good example for when a side effect in the subscript could interfere with an assignment and cause UB.

Comment: @bogdan Never mind. I didn't understand the joke ago :-).  Thanks for your interpretation of that.

Answer (score 4):

The multiply postfix incremented expression is not UB by itself because the standard mandates that:

> The value computation of the ++ expression is sequenced before
> the modification of the operand object.

So in each `x++[arr]`,  the postfix incrementation is defered after the value computation and will end into `arr[0][arr][arr][arr][arr][arr][arr]` and finaly (as `arr[0]` is initialy `0`) into `arr[0]`.

Then you will have a number of incrementation to apply here to the same `arr[0]` element, and as demonstrated by KalilCuk, all will be fine **on that part alone** at least in C++17. As `arr[0]` is `0` all those post incrementation will apply on `arr[0]`, still without UB in that specific user case even before C++17.

The problem is that the assignment is not a sequence point. So a compiler can choose to first apply the assignment and then increment the result (which would give 11), or to first increment the value (which will become 6) and then process the assignment with a final result of 5.

So you are invoking the same UB as the simpler:

```
i = 0;
i++ = 1;     // 1 or 2 ?
```

Probably not the one you expected, but still UB...

Comment: Maybe I should add a tag `c++17`.

Comment: The evaluation sequence for `postfix incremented expression` itselft does not guarante the expression in my question `arr[0]++[arr]...[arr]=5` be well-defined, as I mentioned in this example `int arr[2] = {0};
(*(arr[0]++ + arr))++`, the side effects are unsequenced.

Comment: In addition, `i++ = 1;  ` is ill-formed due to `i++` is a prvalue.

Comment: The result of execution of the original program is distinct between MSVC and gcc/clang. This might be another reason for UB.